# "SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, websocket

I want to deploy with Heroku a very small app (React + Node server) made with Create-React-App, everything works in local but in production, I have this error message :

```
SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

I don't understand the error, because I just have the boilerplate of a React App + Node Server, I'm not using web sockets or anything,

I saw a topic with the same issue (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079#issuecomment-562373869), but I still got the error

My Github repo : https://github.com/Versifiction/ofilms-test-heroku

My site deployed : https://test-ofilms-heroku.herokuapp.com/

Comment: add this lines too in webpackHotDevClient.js pathname: '/sockjs-node',
    slashes: true

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi ok after the addition of this, do I have to do something else?

Comment: delete inside .cache folder and rebuild your product again

Comment: error still here, insane..

Comment: see your website console error! you can see this: attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://test-ofilms-heroku.herokuapp.com/sockjs-node' then I'm sure you did not update webpackHotDevClient.js file with: protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws', or your last build product not in your site

Comment: weird because in the file I did the updates, I did like you said : delete .cache folder and npm run build

Comment: see this error : WebSocket endpoint 'ws://test-ofilms-heroku.herokuapp.com/sockjs-node' ws:// mean your update on file not effected ! if you did it then ws:// changed to wss://

Comment: Check your webserver app host folder, if you have node_modules in your webserver remove it

Comment: but if i remove node modules I lose the edits no?

Comment: This changes should be done on your client not in your server !

Comment: ok it seems to work, but now I have error with the server, can we speak in the stackoverflow chat please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205186/discussion-between-versifiction-and-babak-yaghoobi).

Comment: Interestingly, you might just need to enable insecure content in your browser to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

above issue might be occur due to proxy target is set for your localhost environment.

proxy target found in your code
https://github.com/Versifiction/ofilms-test-heroku/blob/master/src/setupProxy.js

Comment: I started by adding a proxy in the package.json, but when I do so, Heroku says "Invalid Host Header", so I added this proxy file delivered by Create-React-App https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/ for requesting the server with relative paths.. ( axios.get('api/message') will target http://localhost:5000/api/message )

Comment: as specified in the below document

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy                  if you face an invalid host header error To work around it, you can specify your public development host in a file called .env.development in the root of your project:   as **HOST=test-ofilms-heroku.herokuapp.com**

Comment: ok, but I already have .env file, can it creates conflict between these .env ?